# Modifying a jQuery object

Tags: jquery

I have an `<a>` element. I then have an associated jQuery object `$("a")` which I would like to modify. So I try the following:

```
$("a").myAttribute = 10;
alert($("a").myAttribute);    // <--- Alerts undefined
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each use of $('a') returns a different instance of an object. While your original code won't work, you should be able to do:

```
var a = $('a');
a.myAttribute = 10;

alert(a.myAttribute.toString());
```

If you actually want to add the value to the DOM so that you can use it later, the "correct" way would be to use either the attr method (if you're setting a valid HTML attribute) or the data method (if you want to use a non-standard name):

```
// valid HTML attribute
$('a').attr('name', 'someName');

// non-standard name
$('a').data('myAttribute', 10);
```

And then later:

```
alert($('a').attr('name'));
```

Or:

```
alert($('a').data('myAttribute'));
```

If you need something more complex (like storing a complex object rather than a simple attribute/data value), I would consider writing a simple jQuery Plugin which extends the jQuery object and ads the storage/retrieval methods required for your custom object.

To get started with a simple example, check out jQuery's plugin authoring page:

[Plugins/Authoring - jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring)

Comment: Please see the comment I left to Nicola.

Comment: @Randomblue - If you read the last two paragraphs, I've already addressed those comments.

Answer (score 3):

you could do:

```
 $("a").attr('myattribute', '10');//store the attribute
```

In any case you should traget it a little better because with $("a") you ar targeting all links in the page so a better thing to do is:

```
 $("a#myid").attr('myattribute', '10');
```

if you just need to save data related to the object you should use data()

```
 $("a#myid").data('myattribute', '10');
 //to retrieve it use
 var my = $("a#myid").data('myattribute')
 //you can still use 'a' for example a.hide() hides all links
```

EDIT - if you need to attach an object you should consider doing this:

```
  var a = $('a');
  //use the reference from now on
  a.secondObject = SecondjQueryObject
```

Comment: Well actually I would like to do `$("a").someComplexObject = myObject`, not just an attribute.

Comment: so you want to attach an object to a jquery object?

Comment: Thanks. The problem I'm trying to solve is the following. It is natural for my to consider _pairs_ of jQuery objects, so I would like to somehow merge two jQuery objects into one object. Making a "super object" containing both is a problem because it would not be query-able. So I thought of doing `FirstjQueryObject.secondObject = SecondjQueryObject` so that I can still query `FirstjQueryObject`.

Comment: in that case you should make a reference to the first object and use it as kingjiv suggested

Answer (score 0):

Use attr method

```
$("a").attr('myattribute', 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

@nicola is right that you should use `attr`.  However, to clarify the reason that came back undefined.  In the code:

```
$("a").myAttribute = 10;
alert($("a").myAttribute);
```

The first `$("a")` and the 2nd `$("a")` are two separate objects.  Each time you call `$` you are creating a new object.  These objects in this case happen to hold the same set of elements, but they are still two distinct objects.  You are then modifying the first object and checking to see if the modification exists on the 2nd.  Obviously it doesn't.  The following will actually do what you were expecting:

```
var a = $("a");    
a.myAttribute = 10;
alert(a.myAttribute);
```

But this will only modify that specific javascript object and not the element(s) which the objects contain.  This is why you want to use `attr`.  This will actually add the attribute to the underlying elements.

I would suggest looking into `data` though, as I find it a better approach then creating arbitrary attributes.  http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/